# My Website is Mirror-flipped on iPhone Devices

Tags: html, css, iphone, mobile, bootstrap-4

I have a bizarre issue where my static html page implemented with bootstrap and standard css styling becomes mirror-flipped on iPhone 6 but no other device.

I can also not replicate the issue in any console or emulator so I can't find the root of the problem.

If anyone can help you would be a lifesaver, here is an example:

**Unflipped On Other Devices**

[image: Unflipped On Other Devices]

**Flipped On iPhone 6**
[image: Flipped On iPhone 6]

Comment: Can you please provide the URL of your website. Have you tried to load the website on a different iphone 6

Comment: hello viCky I am happy to, here it is: https://wwauth.multiply.co.za/static/partner-benefits-calculator/index.html#packages  **click on the first button to see the page with the problem**

Comment: how do i get the red popup

Answer (score 0):

The issue that you are facing is because you are trying to flip the content. When you use the transform rotate property, on IOS, you are seeing the flipped content. The solution is to use backface-visibility.

```
.card .back {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

An element's back face is a mirror image of its front face. Though invisible in 2D, the back face can become visible when a transformation causes the element to be rotated in 3D space.

You can read more about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility

Comment: The things is there was never an intention to flip the content at any point, so this functionality is coming from somewhere else. How do I override this issue on the random affected devices?

Comment: @DirkSteynberg It´s inside of your main.css Somewhere here  `src/scss/helper/_card.scss` I would say. We don´t know your code/project so we cant help deeper.

Comment: @DirkSteynberg did you try adding the given CSS to your code? This should solve your problem and the mirror effect will go away.

Comment: I have added the code and unfortunately it does not fix the problem. What i have discovered tho is backface-visibility does not work on Safari Browsers. When I inspect the issue on Safari, backface-visibility does not exist in the css.

Comment: Yes, thats why you need to add -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; :) Please add this and your problem will be solved. Also, once your problem is solved, you can click on the tick mark on the left of the answer

Comment: did it solve your problem? if yes, please click on tick button on left of answer